# Strange i64 behavior when calling JavaScript function from C++ using Emscripten:

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

As described [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript) I'm trying to call a JavaScript function `foo()` which takes an 64 bit integer and any other type as arguments from C++:

```
// declaration
extern "C" {
    void foo(int64_t a, int32_t b);
}

// call
foo(123456789, 4);
```

In `foo.js` I implement `foo()`:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  foo: function(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
  }});
```

.. and 'link' it via `--js-library foo.js` to the resulting 'binary' (in my case a shared library.

When I call `foo()` from C++ as shown, the JS implementation get's called but the parameters are broken, e.g. `b` becomes 0, while `a` *seems* to be ok (but in fact only values up to INT_MAX are passed successfully).

When I add another `int32_t` argument I can see that the value for `b` get's *shifted* to *c* - so it looks like `a` is being interpreted as 32 bit value while the next 32 bit of `a` are taken as `b` while `b` is taken as `c`:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbcccc    <- alignment on stack

aaaabbbbcccc        <- interpreted alignment on stack
```

Is this known behavior? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

I'm using EMSDK version `sdk-1.38.28-64bit`.

Comment: might be worth checking out this similar question: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/3369

Comment: javascript has a limitation on size of numeric values. There is only one kind of number in javascript no int no float no double only number with fixed size.I guess this is the problem. There is no native js support for 64bit numbers.

Comment: a workaround would be to use and pass around string values instead of numeric values and handle accordingly or use 2 numeric values for each 64 bit c value

Comment: Shouldn't this be considered a bug in Emscripten then? Compilation/Linking succeeds without a warning/error and the resulting binary contains instructions for 'i64' as expected.